# SMS API that allows you to specify FROM?

Tags: api, sms

I'm wanting to move away from using $phonenumber@$provider domain because it is too limited in usability.

Is there a SMS service with a good API (prefer HTTP/s, XML, JSON) that allows you to send from a specific phone number?

The reason I want it to come from a specific phone number is because I have a Google Voice number I use for my business...

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) will let you set the FROM number to any Twilio number that you own. Of course, you'd have to give up your Google Voice phone number. I'm pretty sure you won't find any SMS service that allows you to set the FROM number to an arbitrary number (just think of the mess it would cause).

See comment below indicating that the Google Voice number could be ported to Twilio.

Comment: I work at Twilio so I can answer any questions about this. In short this answer is correct, though you can port your GV number to us for free and continue using it with our SMS API. Other than that, carriers require that the number sending the message is the actual number that will receive it back.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use your google voice phone number maybe you just want to send the SMS though google voice. One way to connect w/ google voice is to use the Asterisk software. You would use Asterisk to talk to google voice over the SIP protocal - documented here:

http://michigantelephone.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-to-use-google-voice-for-free-outgoing-calls-on-an-asteriskfreepbx-system-the-easy-way/

and

http://eggie5.com/10-installing-asterisk-on-osx

For example I did this and then I interface asterisk from ruby code and can make calls, sms, etc.

Comment: I didn't try the above, but all the articles mentioned it is now out of date, so probably will not work.